# Retrieve IDs with a minimum time gap between consecutive rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following `event` table in Postgres 9.3:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  event_id    integer PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id     integer,
  event_type  varchar,
  event_time  timestamptz
);
```

**My goal** is to retrieve all `user_id`'s with a gap of at least 30 days between any of their events (or between their last event and the current time). An additional complication is that I only want the users who have one of these gaps occur at a later time than them performing a certain `event_type` `'convert'`. How can this be done easily?

Some example data in the `event` table might look like:

```
INSERT INTO event (event_id, user_id, event_type, event_time)
VALUES
(10, 1, 'signIn',  '2015-05-05 00:11'),
(11, 1, 'browse',  '2015-05-05 00:12'),  -- no 'convert' event

(20, 2, 'signIn',  '2015-06-07 02:35'),
(21, 2, 'browse',  '2015-06-07 02:35'),
(22, 2, 'convert', '2015-06-07 02:36'),  -- only 'convert' event
(23, 2, 'signIn',  '2015-08-10 11:00'),  -- gap of >= 30 days
(24, 2, 'signIn',  '2015-08-11 11:00'),

(30, 3, 'convert', '2015-08-07 02:36'),  -- starting with 1st 'convert' event
(31, 3, 'signIn',  '2015-08-07 02:36'),
(32, 3, 'convert', '2015-08-08 02:36'),
(33, 3, 'signIn',  '2015-08-12 11:00'),  -- all gaps below 30 days
(33, 3, 'browse',  '2015-08-12 11:00'),  -- gap until today (2015-08-20) too small

(40, 4, 'convert', '2015-05-07 02:36'),
(41, 4, 'signIn',  '2015-05-12 11:00');  -- gap until today (2015-08-20) >= 30 days
```

Expected result:

```
user_id
--------
2
4
```

Comment: I think I have it. But could you also include your desire output?

Comment: Also please next time try to include a fiddle that help us a lot to work in your problem [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8cbc54)

Comment: So don't list users that have no `'convert'` event at all?

Comment: My guess is  event `convert` --- event A  (30 min)  event B

Comment: So, with your example data, it's really only `event_id` `0005` that would fill the two requirements, so your resultset would be `user_id` `2222`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JNevill yes, except technically user 1111 hasn't done anything since 30 days from his last event, since it is more than 30 days later than 1998.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter correct, exclude users with no `'convert'` event.

Comment: How many 'convert' events can there be per user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
        , lead(e.event_time, 1, now()) OVER (PARTITION BY e.user_id ORDER BY e.event_time)
          - event_time AS gap
   FROM  (  -- only users with 'convert' event
      SELECT user_id, min(event_time) AS first_time
      FROM   event
      WHERE  event_type = 'convert'
      GROUP  BY 1
      ) e1
   JOIN   event e USING (user_id)
   WHERE  e.event_time >= e1.first_time
   ) sub
WHERE  gap >= interval '30 days'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The [window function **`lead()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) allows to include a default value if there is no "next row", which is convenient to cover your additional requirement "or between their last event and the current time".

### Indexes

You should at least have an index on `(user_id, event_time)` if your table is big:

```
CREATE INDEX event_user_time_idx ON event(user_id, event_time);
```

If you do that often and the `event_type` 'convert' is rare, add another partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX event_user_time_convert_idx ON event(user_id, event_time)
WHERE  event_type = 'convert';
```

### For *many* events per user

And only if gaps of 30 days are *common* (not a rare case).
Indexes become even more important.
Try this [recursive CTE](http://%20%20--%20add%201%20row%20after%20last%20to%20consider%20gapt%20till) for better performance:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (  -- parentheses required
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id)
          user_id, event_time, interval '0 days' AS gap
   FROM   event
   WHERE  event_type = 'convert'
   ORDER  BY user_id, event_time
   )

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.user_id, e.event_time, COALESCE(e.event_time, now()) - c.event_time
   FROM   cte c
   LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT e.event_time
      FROM   event e
      WHERE  e.user_id = c.user_id
      AND    e.event_time > c.event_time
      ORDER  BY e.event_time
      LIMIT  1     -- the next later event
      ) e ON true  -- add 1 row after last to consider gap till "now"
   WHERE  c.event_time IS NOT NULL
   AND    c.gap < interval '30 days'
   )
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE  gap >= interval '30 days';
```

It has considerably more overhead, but can stop - per user - at the first gap that's big enough. If that should be the gap between the last event *now*, then `event_time` in the result is NULL.

New [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2556c/2) with more revealing test data demonstrating both queries.

Detailed explanation in these related answers:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Comment: I thiink you didnt include the current date as OP mention

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: That's right. Added a `now()::timestamp` as default to `lead()` to fix that.

Comment: Let's say there are 100's of rows per user. Would the faster queries come into play? Could I see those below this answer?

Comment: @tscizzle: I added another answer. BTW, `now()` returns `timestamptz`, no added cast needed.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fae9e/2)

This is another way, probably not as neat as @Erwin but have all the step separated so is easy to adapt.

- include_today: add a dummy event to indicate current date.
- event_convert: calculate the first time the event `convert` appear for each `user_id` (in this case only `user_id = 2222`)
- event_row: asign an unique consecutive id to each event. starting from 1 for each `user_id`
- last part join all together and using `rnum = rnum + 1` so could calculate date difference.
- also the result show both event involve in the `30 days` range so you can see if that is the result you want.

.

```
WITH include_today as (
     (SELECT 'xxxx' event_id, user_id, 'today' event_type, current_date as event_time
     FROM users)
     UNION
     (SELECT *
     FROM event)
),
event_convert as (
     SELECT user_id, MIN(event_time) min_time
     FROM event
     WHERE event_type = 'convert'
     GROUP BY user_id
),
event_row as (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY event_time desc) as rnum
    FROM 
        include_today 
 )
SELECT 
    A.user_id,
    A.event_id eventA, 
    A.event_type typeA,
    A.event_time timeA,
    B.event_id eventB, 
    B.event_type typeB,
    B.event_time timeB,
    (B.event_time - A.event_time) days
FROM
    event_convert e 
    Inner Join event_row A 
        ON e.user_id = A.user_id and e.min_time <= a. event_time 
    Inner Join event_row B 
        ON A.rnum = B.rnum + 1
       AND A.user_id = B.user_id
WHERE 
   (B.event_time - A.event_time) > interval '30 days'
ORDER BY 1,4
```